# Solve in parametric equations in term of a set of parameters

Tags: equation-solving, variable, parameters

I am not sure the title is right but let me explain.

I have the relations

`b[1] = a[1, 1, 1] + a[1, 2, 2];  b[1, 1] = -a[1, 1, 2]^2 + a[1, 1, 1] a[1, 2, 2];  b[1, 2] = a[1, 2, 2] a[2, 1, 1] - 2 a[1, 1, 2] a[2, 1, 2] + a[1, 1, 1] a[2, 2, 2];  b[2, 2] = -a[2, 1, 2]^2 + a[2, 1, 1] a[2, 2, 2];  b[2] = a[2, 1, 1] + a[2, 2, 2]`

And I want mathematica to express (if possible because I am not sure) b[1,2] in terms of the other $b$ variables, i.e., with no reference to the $a$ variables. I allow for all kind of complicated algebraic expression just that these are all in terms of $b$ and not $a.$

Answer (score 2):

Since you have only 5 equations, you can not eliminate all six a[...] to get one equation with all b's. But Reduce with the command to forced elimination of all a's, gives you at least a few relations for b's. Maybe it helps nevertheless.

```
(eqs = {b[1] == a[1, 1, 1] + a[1, 2, 2], 
b[1, 1] == -a[1, 1, 2]^2 + a[1, 1, 1] a[1, 2, 2], 
b[1, 2] == 
 a[1, 2, 2] a[2, 1, 1] - 2 a[1, 1, 2] a[2, 1, 2] + 
  a[1, 1, 1] a[2, 2, 2], 
b[2, 2] == -a[2, 1, 2]^2 + a[2, 1, 1] a[2, 2, 2], 
b[2] == a[2, 1, 1] + a[2, 2, 2]}) // TableForm

List @@ # & /@ eqs // Flatten // Variables // Sort

red1 = Reduce[eqs, 
  b[1, 2], {a[1, 1, 1], a[1, 1, 2], a[1, 2, 2], a[2, 1, 1], 
  a[2, 1, 2], a[2, 2, 2]}]

TraditionalForm[
red1 //. Or -> 
Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

Restrict to reals

```
red2 = Reduce[eqs, 
  b[1, 2], {a[1, 1, 1], a[1, 1, 2], a[1, 2, 2], a[2, 1, 1], 
  a[2, 1, 2], a[2, 2, 2]}, Reals]

TraditionalForm[
red2 //. Or -> 
Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]